# Sign in Javascript and Verify in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

It is easy to sign and verify in Javascript using existing libraries. However, it is confusing if we want to generate a public-private key pair in Javascript, sign a text and then verify in Flask. I already know some differences, like the default hashing in Javascript side as against python side. However, the verification in Flask side still fails.

**index.html**

```
function send(){
    promise =   window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(algo,
                    true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
                    ["sign", "verify"] //can be any combination of "sign" and "verify"
                    );
    console.log(promise)
    promise.then( (keys) => {
        priv = keys.privateKey
        pub = keys.publicKey
        console.log(pub)
        console.log(exportCryptoKey(pub))
        const pub_key_export = exportCryptoKey(pub)
        return pub_key_export.then( (pub_key) => {
            console.log("storing keys in", pub_key)
            signature = window.crypto.subtle.sign(algo, priv, enc_msg);
            signature.then((sign) => {
                sgn = window.btoa(ab2str(sign));
                $.post("verify", {"pub": pub_key, "data": ab2str(enc_msg), "signature": sgn}, function(data){
                    console.log("data", data);
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

**verify.py**

```
def verifySignature(signature, data, pub_key):
    key = RSA.importKey(pub_key)
    h = SHA256.new(data.encode("utf-8"))
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    return verifier.verify(h, signature)
```

Comment: thats alot of code ... but i noticed you call btoa which is base64 encoding something ... but you dont ever call base64.b64decode in flask

Comment: thanks, this is kinda minimal example. That s a good point, let me check that

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think b64decide was the issue. I also reduced the code. If you want, you can post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btoa(raw_binary_bytes)` will encode your payload into base64 in js, this is done to prevent issues when transmitting raw bytes.

you need to call the decode method in python with `base64.b64decode(encoded_bytes)` to get the actual encrypted bytes, which you can then decrypt